# Websites or software showing pronunciation guide of a phrase or sentence

Tags: pronunciation, resources

I am wondering if there is any website to show the pronunciation as below.

어떻습니까 --> [어 떠 씀 니 까]

좋슴니다   --> [조 씀 니 다]

따뜻합니다 --> [따 뜨 탐 니 다]

With single word, there are some excellent dictionaries doing that as my previous thread. However, when many words are put together to make a phrase or sentence, is there any website or software to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Hong's Hangul Conversion Tools](http://sori.org/hangul/conv2kr.cgi) has a "KR-to-MCT" utility that shows how full sentences are pronounced:

[image: Hong's Hangul Conversion Tools screenshot]

Note, the site gives this description and warning:

> KR-to-MCT: Use this to see how Korean character sequences should be pronounced. This is experimental at best and a work in progress. I tried to follow the standard rules as much as possible, but since there are so many exceptions you should never rely on this.

Answer (score 0):

Both translate.google.com and translate.naver.com can do that. Naver has a much better voice, IMHO.

(I mean, if you are looking for a text-to-speech system. If you are looking for a text-to-text one, it is a totally different matter.)

Comment: I am looking for text to text not text to speech.